# Combine two order by queries to get result

Tags: mysql

I have two queries :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as adet, MONTHNAME(date_created) as monthname
FROM orders 
WHERE YEAR(date_created) = 2017
GROUP BY MONTH(date_created)
```

which returns this result

```
adet monthname 
----------------
17   January
24   February
45   March 
40   April
```

and another query :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as adet, seller_id
FROM orders 
WHERE YEAR(date_created) = 2017
GROUP BY seller_id
```

which returns this result :

```
adet seller_id
---------------
120  20
120  21
500  22
400  23
```

How can I combine those two queries to get the result like this:

```
adet month seller_id
--------------------
-09- -Jan- --20--
-05- -Fab- --20--
-05- -Mar- --20--
...
-05- -jan- --21--
-04- -Fab- --21--
...
-05- -jan- --22--
-04- -Fab- --22--
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) adet, LAST_DAY(date_created) month_ending, seller_id
   FROM orders
  WHERE date_created >= DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%Y-01-01')
    AND date_created < DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%Y-01-01') + INTERVAL 1 YEAR
  GROUP BY LAST_DAY(date_created), seller_id
```

Why would you use something so seemingly complex? Because

1. it will work next year.
2. it will handle ranges of dates which don't end on year boundaries
3. it will be able to use an index on your `date_created` column and therefore run faster.

Answer (score 1):

Try below query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as adet, MONTHNAME(date_created) as monthname,seller_id
FROM orders where YEAR(date_created) = 2017
GROUP BY MONTH(date_created),seller_id
```